# Change sorting new page product

Tags: product-list, new-products, sort

I have a product page /new with a product list sorting by "position" by default.
I don't like this sorting because the list never change...

Is there a mean to change this sort only to this page please?

Comment: Is it a category page you created yourself?

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Dear Klettseb, thank you very much for your answer.
Unfortunately, it seems that it is not a category page I have created myself and I don't find where I could configure it for now.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, either you can do this in the backend if it is a random category page you created like this:

1. Setting default Sort Order for category
   When you go to Category page in Magento administration (Catalog/Manage Categories), you’ll see “Display Settings” tab. From there you can modify “Available Product Listing Sort By” and “Default Product Listing Sort By” values.

[image: Backend]

2. In your **local.xml** you can also change it there.

   ```
       <CATEGORY_YOURCATEGORYID>
           <reference name="product_list">
               <action method="setDefaultDirection"><string>asc</string></action>
               <action method="setDefaultOrder"><string>price</string></action>                
           </reference>
       </CATEGORY_YOURCATEGORYID>
   ```